# HttpURLConnection Proxy strange IOException ("Error writing to server")

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection

I want to create a function which creates a (HTTP)URLConnection thru a Proxy Server.
I have tested this with some free proxys from the internet.
 With all of them (i have tested), **everything works fine**.
But if I run this in my customers network (with customers proxy-server) the code fails at `urlCon.getInputStream()` with an IOException.
I did some tests with Apache HttpClient on the same network (with same proxy-server).
 The Apache HttpClient works fine.
But why does my code (with HttpURLConnection) not work?

**EDIT:** In other words:
Why is my code throwing **only** an exception, when using the customers proxy server?
Why i get **no exception**, when using ApacheHTTPClient and the customers proxy?
Here is my working code:

```
    final String proxyURL = txtProxyURL.getText();
    final String proxyPort = txtProxyPort.getText();
    final String proxyUserName = txtProxyUserName.getText();
    final String proxyPassword = new String(txtProxyPassword.getPassword());

    String sURL = m_mainFrame.getCurrentAdress();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try 
    {            
            HttpURLConnection urlCon;                
            URL testURL = new URL(sURL);                

            Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return (new PasswordAuthentication(proxyUserName, proxyPassword.toCharArray()));
                }
            };
            Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);                

            //Proxy instance, proxy ip = 10.0.0.1 with port 8080
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyURL, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort)));
            urlCon = (HttpURLConnection)testURL.openConnection(proxy);

            urlCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlCon.setDoOutput(true);
            urlCon.setReadTimeout(1000 * 300);
            urlCon.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 300);
            urlCon.connect();

            //!!! HERE THE EXCEPTION OCCURS (when calling getInputStream):
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            char[] cbuf = new char[512];
            while (reader.read(cbuf) > -1)
            {
                String s = new String(cbuf);
                sb.append(s);
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());   

            int responseCode = urlCon.getResponseCode();                
            if (responseCode == 200)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proxy OK for URL: " + sURL);
            else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proxy not OK for URL:"+ sURL + "\r\nIt returns Code: " + responseCode);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();            
    }
```

The code fails with this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor2.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)....

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFields(Unknown Source)
at *.*.webstarter.ui.SettingsDlg.testProxy(SettingsDlg.java:673)
... 84 more
```

Comment: Pass the request through proxy, try this way.

Comment: @ blackOcean: as you can see in my code, the request **is** passed through the proxy `testURL.openConnection(proxy);`

Comment: try this way, because few days back i got struck. getINputStream and getOutputStream will not work, because still there is no connection. You have to create connection by this way and then simply use URL connection. It will work.

Comment: @ blackOcean: Maybe you did not really noticed, but my code is fully working. i got **only an exception**, when using the **clients proxy server** I have no problems using ApacheHTTPClient.

Answer (score -3):

Using TrustManager and Certifications is little cumbersome. One think you can do is pass your request through the proxy.

```
    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyHost", "proxy.url"); // Enter proxy of the url like proxy.domain.com
    System.getProperties().put("https.proxyPort", "port no"); // Enter port no most common is 80 for http.
```

You can check the proxy from the Internet Properties > Connections and then LAN settings. 
After sending the request through the proxy, please set the proxy host and port null.

Use http.proxyHost for httpRequest and use https.proxyHost for httpsRequest.

Comment: My problem has nothing todo with SSL/HTTPS. i simplified my code, however the same problem occurs.

Comment: And don't use code for matting for text  that isn't code.